# Allow selection on disabled form control in Angular 9

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, angular9

I'm using a dynamic form with Angular 9 and i'd like to select text on disabled fields but i'm not able to. 
I use this form for both the edition and the readonly usage.

Here is an exemple of one of the inputs on my form

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" formControlName="title">
```

Do you now how i could allow a text selection on my form controls without enabling the edition on the field?

If you need more details about my code, feel free to ask.

Comment: Instead of disabling it, you could use the ```readonly``` attribute on the input and that will allow you to select the text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Comment: @nullptr.t Thanks for your answer ! I'm going to test it asap